# Python PyPI, asynchronous updates, reactionary requirements, avoid breaking distro - solution I came up with safe? How to automate?

Tags: bash, python, repository, pip, unattended-upgrades

## Context

### Personal context:

Inexperienced Linux user, learning Python, hoping to apply it to Natural Language Processing on NoSQL databases.

#### Why GNU/Linux:

My budget is small, my old gear ain't broke at all, but can't bear the burdens Windows lays on it. Experimented with splurging on new top-of-the-line workstations from manufacturers that used to have a reputation for quality, guarantees, documentation, and good aftermarket service. Went through something like [this](https://youtu.be/MR25BVBsuS0). Not doing so again. GNU/Linux is customizable and, with the right config, very lightweight.

#### Setup:

I've got one of them running MX-19 with Fluxbox as a "desktop environment", another running Fedora 34 with LXQT, and I'm considering setting another up with either Arch or Gentoo, as I'm told that, though time-consuming, installing these would allow me to understand UNIX-like architectures well, and really tailor things to my machines. I'm falling in love with Linux the way Sam Vimes fell in love with Lady Sybil - started off just glad for what I could get, but the more acquainted I got, the more in love I fell.

It's not entirely free of conflict, though, no pun intended.

#### The Problems with GNU/Linux Distros, which aggravates The Problem With Python:

Most applications and librariess I use are Python-based packages as needed, but they're not always included in distro-authorized repos, nor are they always up to date, if included at all.

Aside from my work, this also applies to the ProtonVPN client and ProtonMail bridge, which are darlings of mine. I install them in every system I have. On Windows and Android, it's trivial, and Debian and Fedora have supported rpm, but their fork distros don't necessarily do so. So I had to resort to the next best thing:

### Installing from PyPI and Installing from Source:

So I've been installing from PyPI using

```
pyton3 -m pip install <packagename>
```

In cases where the software maker doesn't update their PyPI copy, or updates one of their pieces of software and not the other while they are both reliant on different versions of the same libraries, creating dependency conflicts... well, I need to compile from source. I clone the git, cd to the source's root directory, and run:

```
 pyton3 -m pip install .
```

#### Dependency Management Problems: the Special Case of Python & pip:

- this year was the painful transition between python 2.7 and python 3... we're already up to the nines, the elevens are under discussion, pip likewise updates frequently and then warns you constantly if it's not up-to-date.
- meanwhile, a lot of developers have excessively strict requirements: "my software needs this specific version of this package - not 'later than', no, this one specifically" or "no more recent than". Typical solution: use a virtual environment. Two problems with that:

  - having virtual environments for every single package is complicated to keep track of and manage, and my old gear has limited drive and RAM that I can't be frivolous with.
  - deciding which packages to put in virtual environments and which not to is its own time-consuming problem.
  - even with a venv, if the dependence tree of packages contains contradictions, you can end up with an endless cycle of pip installing a package's upgrade that requires another's downgrade, which in turn pip'll then want to upgrade, which will cause conflict with the first one, etc.

    - For example, a package has RequirementA < 2.1.5 and RequirementB >2.3, but versions of A previous to 2.1.5 require C < 4.1 while versions of B > 2.4 require C > 5.2. C can't be > 5.2 AND < 4.1. It can turn into [a bit of a comedy routine.](https://youtu.be/tVLQ8lNd1Pk?t=81)

## The Question Proper:

I've come up with something that seems to work for now, which I'll be putting as a reply below, but I'm not confident that I did it well. It should be straightforward to automate, with some bash scripting, pipes, regex... But, before I commit to this particular approach and make it systemic, I'd like to hear the opinions of experienced Linux users. What, in your judgment, would be a method that:

a) ideally takes advantage of GNU/Linux's unique strengths, while also
b) not messing up whichever particular distro one may be using,
c) that is algorithmically sound and safe to execute
d) that could be reasonably automated for unattended upgrade, and
e) which would check for mistakes along the way and allow me to walk them back?
- Especially when it comes to installing from source, which usually requires getting required dependencies from PyPl anyway.

Comment: IMO your best option is to build .deb packages for your python libraries.  There's a tool called `debdry` which can automate this process (either fully, or at least partially, depending on the package).   There's kind of a cultural conflict with python (in particular) and distros - python devs, by and large, tend to regard the OS as a problem to be worked around, subverted, and bypassed, not as something to be worked with.

Comment: It's a variation of the cultural conflict between programmers and sysadmins.  sysadmins tend to want the *system* as a whole to work and be consistent, even if that means taking more time to make sure everything works well together. Programmers generally want their stuff to work, right now, and to hell with everything else.   There is value in both approaches, but the latter tends to have all sorts of long-term problems because it is an inherently short-term focus.

Comment: Devops, when done right, was supposed to be the solution to this, bringing both mind-sets together. In practice, it mostly means not having to have a dedicated sysadmin on staff (and pay them), and making the most junior programmer on the team do all the sysadmin stuff without really knowing what a sysadmin does.   `pip` is an example of what you get when you approach a sysadmin-type task with a programmer's mind-set. it kind of works, but relies on the user having a very specific idiosyncratic environment in their home directory.  it works for them, so it's good enough for general release.

Comment: The reason I mention all this is because solving this problem requires knowing about the conflict and understanding the differences in mind-set (and goals, and approaches, and methods), otherwise you'll never be able to integrate them well enough to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### The improvised ad-hoc solution :

After much trial and error and irreparably breaking one of my distros by using pip as a sudo, I finally found a way.  By exploring the help guides of pip's options, I find that it is possible to do follow this route, which has not caused me problems *yet*:

1. check for all upgradable packages:

   ```
    python3 -m pip list --outdated --verbose
   ```
2. check for all requirement conflicts:

   ```
    python3 -m pip check --verbose
   ```
3. while there exists a requirement conflict that is because a package is older than is required OR not installed at all, install it, *without dependencies,* then, return to 2. If all requirement conflicts are because a package, that is installed, is too recent for the requirement, move on to step 4.

   ```
    python3 -m pip install --no-dependencies --verbose <package-name>
   ```
4. re-check stage 1, then upgrade one package that is upgradable, *without dependencies*, then repeat the stage 2-3 loop until you're back here in stage 4. Repeat this wider loop until
   a) there are no longer any upgradable packages, and
   b) all installed packages' required  dependencies are themselves installed and either
   - recent enough or
   - 'too recent'.
5. call it a day and move on the next task, wondering if
   a) this may cause problems and possibly break my system and
   b) I could safely bash-script this simple algorithm into a loop

### The ability to walk back mistakes:

I don't really know yet what are the states that would require walkbacks, but I know they'll exist.

That's why all the commands I wrote above are --verbose, so that all information I could gather, and hopefully more than I need, is displayed in the console for me to store in a history. So far I've meticulously done

```
history >> ~/Documents/shell_histories/2021_mm_dd_pip_<upgrades,sourceinstalls,etc.>.txt
```

But I don't know what to do with these logs just yet.

What is your advice?  Is my way valid, or is it reckless? Either way, how can I do better?